# Tableau Desktop - add calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to add on a map a calculated field, that show the progression between 2 values overtime. So I did this on a separated views, using the month, the value and using a double table calculation to get that. But now I want to add it to my map view and I can't get the Date property on it without breaking everything (I only can use the latitude and the longitude) which is a problem I encountered on another views aswell.

So is there a way to add a dimension to a view, but define it as unused (so it does not appear on the graph, or modify the data already there on any way), so I can use my calculated properties and display it as a tooltip for example. Or maybe another way to achieve this since I'm a little stucked right now :)

Comment: Can you please share more information such as screenshot/exact calculations used/Error faced. It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: At the least add screenshot so that we can understand what is your problem

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to add your [Date] field to the tooltip pill on either map. Will that work in this case?